# How can I make a shiny `selectInput()` overflow a `bslib::navset_card_pill()`?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, bslib

### The issue:

My problem is that my `selectInput()` is cut off by the lower border of the card:

```r
library(shiny) # Version 1.7.4
library(bslib) # Version 0.5.0

ui <- page_fluid(
  navset_card_pill(nav_panel(
    title = "No overflow :(",
    selectInput("test", NULL, letters)
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

### A solution with `card()`:

I've managed to solve the problem using `card()`, as this allows you to set a custom class for the card/card body. However `navset_card_pill()` and `nav_panel()` don't allow this, so this particular solution doesn't carry over.

```r
ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
    .foo {
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
  "))),
  
  card(
    class = "foo",
    selectInput("test", NULL, letters),
    wrapper = function(...) card_body(..., class = "foo")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

### Edit #1

I've now found a solution which involves modifying several css classes as follows:

```r
ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
    .bslib-card, .tab-content, .tab-pane, .card-body {
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
  "))),
  navset_card_pill(nav_panel(
    title = "Overflow achieved!",
    selectInput("test", NULL, letters)
  ))
)
```

This isn't ideal though - ideally I'd like to achieve this behaviour without modifying 'global' defaults for these classes throughout my app.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `shinyWidgets::pickerInput`, you can let the dropdown overflow by setting `options = list(container = "body")`

```
shinyWidgets::pickerInput("test", NULL, letters, options = list(container = "body"))
```